# Linked duplicate of parent/children: how to link transform properties of children?

Tags: parent, linked-data

Let's say I have a cube and a sphere, and I make the cube the parent of the sphere. Then I link-duplicate both the cube and sphere with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. Then I start moving/rotating/etc. the duplicates around in object mode, together as a unit.

Later, I discover that I want to change the position of the sphere (child) with respect to the cube (parent). I re-position the original sphere, but the duplicate sphere does not change position.

I can manually copy the transform values from the original to the duplicate, but is there a way to automatically have the transform values be linked?

Answer (score 5):

## In Blender 2.8+, this has changed a bit from @sambler's answer.

Changes since older versions:

- Groups are now superseded by something called Collections (see [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rYaBDcHG6U))
- The "Duplication" setting in an empty is now superseded by a section called "Instancing".

#### The updated steps are:

- Select the objects you want to duplicate.
- Add them to a new Collection by right clicking or using hotkey `M`.
- You can rename the Collection so that it is more meaningful.
- Add an empty
- Set the empty's Instancing setting to "Collection" and choose the collection you
  created.
- Repeat the last two steps as needed.

[image: Instancing in Blender 2.8+]

Comment: An easier way to achieve the same is to just add objects to a Collection. Then, _Add > Collection Instance_ (`Shift + A`) gives a submenu with Collections, and the selected Collection will be placed as an instance of a new empty at the cursor's location. At least with Blender 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

To duplicate multiple objects in different positions and keep the relationship between each instance, you want to use [DupliGroups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupligroup.html).

- Select the objects you want to duplicate.
- Add them to a group <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
- You can rename the group so that it is more meaningful.
- Add an empty
- Set the empties Duplication setting to group and choose the group you created.
- Repeat the last two steps as needed.

[image: dupligroup settings]

Comment: In Blender 2.8 it's unclear where the "Duplication" setting is